# What can I do to check if someone is disconnecting me from internet?

Tags: networking, internet

In the last 8-10 months my internet is getting disconnected 50-60 times a day, sometimes 10-12 times an hour. I have contacted my ISP 20-30 times. Officers of ISP are telling me that everything is alright on their side. I have just run a full scan with KIS 2016 and no threat has been detected inside my computer. I suspect that someone with malicious intent is disconnecting me from internet. I want to know what I can do to detect and prevent that. A recent log is given below. The IP address has been hidden for security reasons. I am using Netgear DGN 1000.

Information:

- This is not a hardware issue because the problem persists even after
  replacing the current modem-router with a D-Link modem.

Log:

```
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:18:19 - Initialize LCP.
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:18:16 - [Internet disconnected]
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:18:13 - Initialize LCP.
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:18:10 - [Internet disconnected]
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:18:06 - Initialize LCP.
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:18:04 - [Internet disconnected]
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:17:48 - Initialize LCP.
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:17:45 - [Internet disconnected]
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:17:42 - Initialize LCP.
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:17:40 - [Internet disconnected]
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:17:36 - Initialize LCP.
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:17:30 - [Internet disconnected]
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:17:24 - Initialize LCP.
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:17:22 - [Internet disconnected]
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:17:19 - Initialize LCP.
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:17:16 - [Internet disconnected]
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:17:13 - Initialize LCP.
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:17:06 - [Internet disconnected]
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:16:58 - Initialize LCP.
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:16:55 - [Internet disconnected]
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:16:53 - Initialize LCP.
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:16:50 - [Internet disconnected]
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:16:47 - Initialize LCP.
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:16:45 - [Internet disconnected]
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:16:41 - Initialize LCP.
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:16:39 - [Internet disconnected]
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:16:30 - Initialize LCP.
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:16:27 - [Internet disconnected]
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:16:24 - Initialize LCP.
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:16:21 - [Internet disconnected]
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:16:18 - Initialize LCP.
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:16:09 - [Internet disconnected]
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:16:08 - Initialize LCP.
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:16:06 - [Internet disconnected]
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:15:42 - [Internet disconnected]
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:15:38 - [Internet disconnected]
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:15:18 - Administrator login successful - IP:192.168.0.2
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:14:41 - [Internet disconnected]
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:14:38 - LCP down - User request .
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:04:26 - [Internet connected] IP address [DATA HIDDEN] 
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:04:25 - CHAP authentication success
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:04:25 - LCP is allowed to come up.
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:04:24 - Initialize LCP.
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:04:22 - [Internet disconnected]
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:03:17 - [Internet disconnected]
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:02:00 - Initialize LCP.
Sun, 2015-11-08 00:01:57 - [Internet disconnected]
```

Comment: Do you have any power-saving features enabled?

Comment: @geek1011 In Router or OS?

Comment: @Ramhound Can't someone disconnect me from internet and then use my connection to surf the internet?

Comment: Both Router and OS.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming: Your service is ADSL

What you're seeing is PPPoE disconnects and re-links. There are a few things that will cause this:

- Sync Issues: Ruled out as log should show sync messages
- DSLAM to RAS: ISP side network issue, common with overloaded or malfunctioning links. Heavy users will see the most disconnects. Not uncommon for ISP to deny its occurring.
- Multiple PPPoE clients on one CSI: If anything else on your network is attempting a PPPoE call to the RAS it will drop the existing session. This will cause a looping disconnect. Check all games consoles, NAS, CCTV cameras and computers for a PPPoE connection enabled. If so, disable it. CCTV and Consoles are the most common culprit.

Finally, make sure your connection is set to pinned up/always on in the modem, but if it happened before you bought the netgear its unlikely to be that.

Comment: @Line4ult Can't someone disconnect me from internet and then use my connection to surf the internet?

Comment: @SusanW.Burr: With some difficulty, possibly. But it is by far not the most likely cause. Just like KIC 8462852 *could* be aliens, but there are plenty of other things that should be ruled out first.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq 1st bullet point has been cancelled by the answerer. I don't know (it's not possible for me to know) if the second bullet point in this answer is the case, but it's not the 3rd one because my pc is the only thing connected to the modem-router. Do you have anything else to rule out?

Comment: @Ramhound Haven't you heard about MITM attack?

Comment: @Linef4ult - There are sync issues.  In the log the author provided there is an error message "LCP down - User request" which means "that the router is (momentarily) loosing sync.".

Comment: @Ramhound How can I solve the sync issues?

Comment: @Ramhound Not quite, LCP is L2, Sync loss would be an L1 disc. Its losing its connection to the RAS(BRAS).